Find a specific ID from the array javascript dynamoDB(local)
This is Array
response:
  {
      "sk": "srName",
      "Name" : "John"
    },
    {
      "sk": "srName",
      "Name": "Brian"
    }
  ]

I'm trying to write code in javascript to GET specific item from above array
GET http://localhost:3000/6666ad97-53bf-4557-8b19-a552a75edd39
response should be:
[
    {
        "Id": "6666ad97-53bf-4557-8b19-a552a75edd39",
        "Name" : 'Brian'
       
    }
]


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

To get an item in a list, you have to pass in either the index or the total value of the object, which you are not.
I suggest that you vertically partition then data that each item in the list is it's own item in DynamoDB.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-vertical-partitioning-to-scale-data-efficiently-in-amazon-dynamodb/
